# Mongoose find by field in inner object (ObjectID)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

For example I have two models

```
const User = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});
```

```
const Message = new Schema({
  user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  message: { type: String },
});
```

How to find messages by the key "name" in the user?

It doesn't work

```
exports.get = async (req, res) => {
  return Message.find({ "user.name": req.query.name })
    .populate('user', 'name')
    .then((data) => res.json(data));
}
```

I understand why "user.name" doesn't work, but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) -> unwind -> match:

Unwind: convert user array to user object from look up stage

```
exports.get = async (req, res) => {
  return Message.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "user",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$user",
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "user.name": req.query.name,
      },
    },
  ])
  .then((data) => res.json(data));
}
```

Comment: I already tried this way. 

But all objects are returned. 

And it also replaces the user field with an array of users by which it was found in bd. 

Screenshots:
[before](https://prnt.sc/DRcH7v-mQV-B)
[after](https://prnt.sc/Jfk5WZCZ06GI)

Comment: My bad, the key is the `{ $ne: [] }` in the skip operation. Please see my edited answer @OlehKhashchevskyi

Comment: the same. see screenshots

Comment: @OlehKhashchevskyi Try my latest edit using `lookup -> unwind -> match`

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a *join* in Mongodb. Hence I would recommend using straight schema definition like this:

```js
const User = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

const Message = new Schema({
  user: [User],
  message: { type: String },
});
```

then you wouldn't need to use `populate` anymore. Instead, you would have something like this:

```js
Message.find({ "user.name": req.query.name })
```

---

However, If you still prefer to use the current approach, You can try this:

```
Message.find()
  .populate({
    path: "user",
    match: {
      name: req.query.name
    }
  })
...
```

Comment: I want to save only ID in database. And if I will be return with populate and match. And will be use limit. How should I know their count in the database? 

`
db.collection.find(params)
db.collection.find(params).count()
`

Comment: Ok, what is exactly your requirement? The current answer will find all *messages* with the given `user.name`. although if there is no match found, the user field would be *null*. By chaining with `count` it counts the number of *messages*, not *users*. Do you want to count users?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need the correct ordering of table
User must be your primary table and Messages must be your secondary table from which you should lookup.
The query is as following;

```
exports.get = async (req, res) => {
const queryLength = req.query.name ? req.query.name.length : 0;
return User.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            name: {
                "$regex": req.query.name,
                "$options": '-i'
            }
        },
        $lookup: {
            let: { id: _id },
            from: 'Messages',
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$user", "$$id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        user: 0,
                        _id: 0,

                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "Messages"
        },
        $project: {
            regex_match: {
                $eq: [
                    req.query.name,
                    { $substr: [{ $toLower: "$name" }, 0, queryLength] }
                ]
            },
            Messages: 1
        },
        $sort: {
            regex_match: -1//we use regex match to get the most match result on the top like if u search "Al" then all results with al in them will be on top
        },
        $project: {
            Messages: 1,
            regex_match: 0
        }
    }

])
    .then((data) => res.json(data));
```

}

This will return all the messages as an array with field name messages of "name" person e.g;

```
{
   Messages: [{_id: 1234, message: "Hello"},{_id: 12345, message: "Hi"} ]
}
```

Comment: but I want to get only array with messages, where client name includes search.  `name: {'$regex': regex}`

Comment: i have updated the answer.
You can check now

Comment: this query will return an array of objects which contain only messages array in sorted order, and sort is base on req.query.name